# Is there a way to use ST_BUFFER on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking for a way to use `ST_BUFFER` function on Snowflake, but can't find it in the documentation. Is there an alias for this function or is there a way to replicate it?

Comment: Here is a list of Geometric functions. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-geospatial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think they have support for geometry buffers at this stage. ST_AREA isn't going to help you. Last I heard they are working on improving their geospatial support.

That said, can you buffer your data somewhere else in your workflow? Such as using shapely buffer in python, or turf circle/buffer in javascript?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look up for a way to do this outside of Snowflake for now.

Answer (score 0):

As said above you can find all geospatial functions here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-geospatial.html

Regarding ST_BUFFER I think the function ST_AREA sounds good: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/st_area.html